# UPDATE on INNER JOIN throwing 'SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL1 = 'UPDATED'  
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
WHERE COL2 = '1' AND COL3 IN('A','B') AND COL4 = 'NEW'
```

The above command throwing 'SQL command not properly ended', may I know why is it happening?
NOTE: COL2 , COL2 resides in TABLE1 while COL4 In TABLE2, if that is helpful.

Comment: Qualify your column names so it is clear what table they come from.

Comment: @GordonLinoff like TABLE1.COL2?

Comment: It is happening because you can't have "INNER JOIN" after "SET" - where did you find that syntax? If you need help fixing it, rather than just an explanation for why THIS doesn't work, please explain what you are trying to do. (Perhaps that can be guessed from your attempt, but generally guessing from an attempt that DOESN'T work is a bad idea.)

Comment: Wrong syntax Must be Update ... join ... set ..,,

Comment: no luck on adding SET after JOIN, saying missing SET keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support explicit join's in its `update` syntax (it does support joins when using subqueries under certain conditions).  A query like this should work:

```
update TABLE1 
    set COL1 = 'UPDATED' 
    where col2 = '1' and col3 in ('A', 'B') and col4 = 'NEW' and
          exists (select 1
                  from TABLE2
                  where TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
                 );
```

The conditions in the `where` may need to go in the subquery, if they refer to `TABLE2`.

Comment: Oracle **does** support joins in `update`, I wish you would stop saying it doesn't. You are among the reasons I felt it necessary to write the documentation entry about it - and I told you several times about this. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201707082024504655365

Comment: I view that Oracle supports *subqueries*, but not `join`s in the syntax.

Comment: @mathguy Could you please make an answer showing how to do it?  I would like to know too - it isn't just the OP that wonders.

Comment: I don't know what "I view" means. Oracle supports `join` in the `update` syntax. I provided a link to the documentation article. If you find fault with it, please feel free to comment on that article, showing how Oracle does **not** support that syntax. (It will be hard to show that, since it works perfectly fine.)

Comment: I'm really confused which is the most suited anser, till then Gordon's query is working for me ( only when putting where in subquery), but what are you trying to convey MathGuy?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Is the column `id` unique (perhaps primary key) in `table2` - is it constrained or indexed that way? If not, the `update` itself does not make sense (one row in the target table must read from two different rows in the source table - that is not possible, the update must be well determined). Please see the documentation article, it is pretty short and has an example just like yours.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - Nothing wrong with Gordon's answer, that is certainly one way to do it. My objection is to the statement that Oracle does not support `join` in `update` - that is simply not true.

Comment: @Rahul if he gives an example that works he doesn't need Oracle to explicitly say that it works, does he?  The example should be proof enough.

Comment: @Rahul - which claim do you not see? The claim that `join` syntax is permitted in an `update`? How can you miss that in the link?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah IMO the bottom line is Oracle refuses updates with a potentially unpredictable result. So it follows the syntax which applies the  UPDATE to a table expression (JOIN or whatever). DBMS checks if the table expression is updatable and infers which underlying table to update .  Contrary to that Ms sql-server for example allows for unpredictable updates and has different syntax for UPDATE where JOIN is used in a different way (not for producing table expression).

Comment: @Serg Thanks for the clarification.